# How to loop through an array of data in React-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

map function is used but it returns endless loop on console.log and i cannot render the rows in return jsx also tried the foreach but its no help. cannot render the data in jsx. its possible to console .log the data even inside the the loop . but not on the render jsx.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity,DrawerLayoutAndroid,Picker,ListView } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Title, Content,List, ListItem, Text, Button, Icon,InputGroup, Input,View } from 'native-base';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import axios from 'axios';
import styles from '../styles/homestyle';
export default class Home extends Component {

constructor(props) {

super(props);

this.state = {
  user_namez : "",
  user_pazz : "",
};
}
student_data(){

axios.get('http://192.168.0.108/easy_backend/app/app_db/stud_data')

.then((response) => {

  let respdata = response.data ;

  list.respdata(function(y){

    return(<Text>{y.prnt_usernamez}</Text>);

  });

  });

  }

  render() {

   return (

   <View>

    {this.student_data()}

    </View>
    ) 

   } 



   }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`student_data()` doesn't return anything. So nothing will never render from `student_data()`.

For asyncronous calls, you must use `componentDidMount()`.

- add a node `response: [],` in Home `state`,
- fill it in a `componentDidMount()` function
- Then loop on `this.state.response` in the `render()` method

Something like:

```
    export default class Home extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                response: [],
                user_namez: "",
                user_pazz: "",
            };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            axios.get('http://192.168.0.108/easy_backend/app/app_db/stud_data')
            .then((response) => {
                //as soon as the state is updated, component will render using updated values
                this.setState({ response: response});
            });
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    {
                        this.state.response.map((y) => {
                            return (<Text>{y.prnt_usernamez}</Text>);
                        })
                    }
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Different ways to loop through arrays and objects in React

## Javascript — map()

```
{arrayData.map(d => {
  return (<Text>{d.element_key}</Text>);
})}
```

## Javascript for Loop

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
  // code block to be executed
}
```

## Javascript forEach Loop

```
data.forEach(
   function(d){
     forEachData += '<li>' + d.name + '</li>'
    }
 )
```